# Merge fields of object to create new field with Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a collection that I’d like to grab some values from, and merge them together to form a new value. So far I’ve looked at `R.evolve`, but with no luck (because `medias` is also a collection.

This is what I’m starting with:

```
[{
  "permalink": "http://example.com/1",
  "medias": [{
    "filename": "image_1.png",
  }]
}, {
  "permalink": "http://example.com/3",
  "medias": [{
    "filename": "image_3.png",
  }]
}]
```

And this is what I’d like to end with:

```
[{
  "permalink": "http://example.com/1",
  "medias": [{
    "filename": "image_1.png",
    "image_url": "http://example.com/1/image_1.png"
  }]
}, {
  "permalink": "http://example.com/3",
  "medias": [{
    "filename": "image_3.png",
    "image_url": "http://example.com/3/image_3.png"
  }]
}]
```

Essentially what we’re doing is prepending each `filename` with a `permalink`.

This is the kind of thing I’ve been going for so far, unfortunately when running the transform on `medias`, I can’t get access to the `permalink` property.

```
const mapMedia = R.map(
  // can’t get access to the `permalink` in here?
)

const transformations = {
  medias: mapMedia
}

const transform = R.compose(
  R.map(R.evolve(transformations)),
)(data)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Sure! Have just added in my attempt so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is that the data you need is not in scope.  In my opinion, the easiest way to fix that is to add some scope!

First off, you don't need that `compose` call, since you're only supplying it one function.  So we can replace

```
const transform = R.compose(
  R.map(R.evolve(transformations)),
)(data)
```

with just

```
const transform = R.map(R.evolve(transformations)),
```

(I also removed the call with `(data)`, since I'm trying to build this up as a reusable function.  We would then call it later with `transform(data)`.

Now we have to add context so that `transformations` has the object in scope.  We can do that like this:

```
const transform = R.map(image => R.evolve(transformations(image), image));
```

Of course that means `transformations` needs to change to take this into account.  We can do that like this:

```
const transformations = image => ({
  medias: mapMedia(image.permalink)
})
```

... and this in turn requires a change to `mapMedia`.  I thought that it should only need to know about the permalink and not the entire image, so we can pass only that as above.  And `mapMedia` would now look like this:

```
const mapMedia = permalink => R.map(
  medium => // do something with `medium` and `permalink`
);
```

There are many ways that you could do this last step.  One of them, fairly aligned to your use of [`evolve`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) would be this:

```
const mapMedia = permalink => R.map(
  medium => assoc('image_url', permalink + '/' + medium.filename, medium)
);
```

Another alternative to both `evolve` and [`assoc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc) is to investigate the various `lens`-related functions in Ramda, such as [`lensProp`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensProp), [`over`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#over), and [`set`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#set).

Now, if those helper functions are only used for this purpose, you might not want them cluttering things up, and you could choose to inline them in your main function.  If you liked, you might combine all the above into

```
const addUrls = map(
  image => evolve({
    medias: map(medium => assoc('image_url', image.permalink + '/' + medium.filename, medium)),
  }, image)
);
```

You can see the **[separate functions](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20coll%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%22permalink%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F1%22%2C%0A%20%20%22medias%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22filename%22%3A%20%22image_1.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22filename%22%3A%20%22image_1.svg%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%22permalink%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F3%22%2C%0A%20%20%22medias%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22filename%22%3A%20%22image_3.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20mapMedia%20%3D%20permalink%20%3D%3E%20R.map%28%0A%20%20medium%20%3D%3E%20assoc%28%27image_url%27%2C%20permalink%20%2B%20%27%2F%27%20%2B%20medium.filename%2C%20medium%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20transformations%20%3D%20image%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20medias%3A%20mapMedia%28image.permalink%29%0A%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20transform%20%3D%20R.map%28image%20%3D%3E%20R.evolve%28transformations%28image%29%2C%20image%29%29%3B%0A%0Atransform%28coll%29)** approach or the **[combined one](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.0#?const%20coll%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%22permalink%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F1%22%2C%0A%20%20%22medias%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22filename%22%3A%20%22image_1.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22filename%22%3A%20%22image_1.svg%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%22permalink%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F3%22%2C%0A%20%20%22medias%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22filename%22%3A%20%22image_3.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20addUrls%20%3D%20map%28%0A%20%20image%20%3D%3E%20evolve%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20medias%3A%20map%28medium%20%3D%3E%20assoc%28%27image_url%27%2C%20image.permalink%20%2B%20%27%2F%27%20%2B%20medium.filename%2C%20medium%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20image%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0AaddUrls%28coll%29%3B%0A)** in the Ramda REPL.  For good measure, there's also a **[version using lenses](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.0#?const%20coll%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%22permalink%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F1%22%2C%0A%20%20%22medias%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22filename%22%3A%20%22image_1.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22filename%22%3A%20%22image_1.svg%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%22permalink%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F3%22%2C%0A%20%20%22medias%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22filename%22%3A%20%22image_3.png%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20addUrls%20%3D%20map%28%0A%20%20image%20%3D%3E%20over%28%0A%20%20%20%20lensProp%28%27medias%27%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20map%28medium%20%3D%3E%20set%28lensProp%28%27image_url%27%29%2C%20image.permalink%20%2B%20%27%2F%27%20%2B%20medium.filename%2C%20medium%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20image%0A%20%20%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0AaddUrls%28coll%29%3B%0A)**.

---

(And on a separate note, the word "media" is already plural.  The singular is "medium".  There's no good reason for "medias".)

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough and excellent answer. This is one of the reasons I like using Ramda so much!

Comment: This is an amazing response.